# Writing Unicode to .docx file

Tags: python, unicode, python-docx

Is there any way to write unicode characters to docx files? I tried [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/) but, it's giving me `TypeError`.

**Traceback**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "< ipython-input-1-ba89c735995d >", line 1, in 
>       runfile('H:/Python/Practice/new/download.py', wdir='H:/Python/Practice/new')
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "H:/Python/Practice/new/download.py", line 37, in 
>       document.add_paragraph(story.encode("utf-8"))
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\document.py", line 63, in add_paragraph
>       return self._body.add_paragraph(text, style)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\blkcntnr.py", line 36, in add_paragraph
>       paragraph.add_run(text)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\text\paragraph.py", line 37, in add_run
>       run.text = text
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\text\run.py", line 163, in text
>       self._r.text = text
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\oxml\text\run.py", line 104, in text
>       _RunContentAppender.append_to_run_from_text(self, text)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\oxml\text\run.py", line 134, in append_to_run_from_text
>       appender.add_text(text)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\oxml\text\run.py", line 142, in add_text
>       self.add_char(char)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\oxml\text\run.py", line 156, in add_char
>       elif char in '\r\n':
>
> TypeError: 'in < string >' requires string as left operand, not int

I was trying to scrape a website and write the texts to a MS Word file. Texts are in local language (Bangla). When I print `story` on console it prints the whole texts perfectly.

**Code**

```
import requests
from docx import Document
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "some url"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

story = soup.find("div", {"dir": "ltr"}).get_text().replace("<br />", "\n", len(response.text))

title = "title"
document = Document()
document.add_heading(title, 0)
document.add_paragraph(story.encode("utf-8"))
document.save(title + ".docx")
```

Comment: I've added full traceback. Btw, it gets data perfectly from the `URL`. When I print it on console it works fine.

Comment: Have you tried *not* calling `.encode('utf-8')`?

Comment: If I don't use `encode("utf-8")` it gives me a document consisting of some blocks.

Comment: Any chance it's because the font doesn't support those characters? If you select those blocks and paste into the browser, would they appear as normal characters?

Comment: Oh thanks !! Pasting those blocks in the browser works, browser showing the characters as normal. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, `str`ings (should) automatically support Unicode, so you don't need to do anything special like encoding-to-UTF-8.

```
document.add_paragraph(story)
#                      ^ just do this directly, no need to call `.encode('utf-8')`
```

While you can write Unicode characters into the document, the default text rendering engine used by the word processor may not support it. You may need to [specify a font](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/text.html#apply-character-formatting) to ensure the characters won't become □□□□.

```
run = document.add_paragraph(story).add_run()
font = run.font
font.name = 'Vrinda'
```